# Adding requestTimeout causes Kibana to fail at startup

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am experimenting with Elasticsearch-Kibana-Logstash for processing web log files.

Some of the queries take a bit of time and Kibana times out quickly, so I wanted to increase the amount of time that Kibana will wait for a response from elasticsearch. After a bit of searching, I found some suggestions to set `elasticsearch.requestTimeout`. I tried to increase the timeout by adding this to my kibana.yml file:

```
elasticsearch.requestTimeout: 5000
```

This causes Kibana to fail immediately on startup with this error:

```
kibserver_1        | FATAL { Error: Payload timeout must be shorter than socket timeout: POST /elasticsearch/{index}/_search
kibserver_1        |     at Object.exports.assert (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:736:11)
kibserver_1        |     at new module.exports.internals.Route (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/hapi/lib/route.js:69:10)
kibserver_1        |     at internals.Connection._addRoute (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/hapi/lib/connection.js:387:19)
kibserver_1        |     at internals.Connection._route (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/hapi/lib/connection.js:379:18)
kibserver_1        |     at internals.Plugin._apply (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/hapi/lib/plugin.js:572:14)
kibserver_1        |     at internals.Plugin.route (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/hapi/lib/plugin.js:542:10)
kibserver_1        |     at createProxy (/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/elasticsearch/lib/create_proxy.js:85:14)
kibserver_1        |     at ScopedPlugin.init [as externalInit] (/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/elasticsearch/index.js:110:37)
kibserver_1        |     at ScopedPlugin.tryCatcher (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
kibserver_1        |     at Promise.attempt.Promise.try (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/method.js:30:24)
kibserver_1        |     at /usr/share/kibana/src/server/plugins/plugin.js:196:46
kibserver_1        |     at next (native)
kibserver_1        |     at step (/usr/share/kibana/src/server/plugins/plugin.js:25:191)
kibserver_1        |     at /usr/share/kibana/src/server/plugins/plugin.js:25:361
kibserver_1        |   cause: 
kibserver_1        |    Error: Payload timeout must be shorter than socket timeout: POST /elasticsearch/{index}/_search
kibserver_1        |        at Object.exports.assert (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:736:11)
kibserver_1        |        at new module.exports.in how to resolternals.Route (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/hapi/lib/route.js:69:10)
kibserver_1        |        at internals.Connection._addRoute (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/hapi/lib/connection.js:387:19)
kibserver_1        |        at internals.Connection._route (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/hapi/lib/connection.js:379:18)
kibserver_1        |        at internals.Plugin._apply (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/hapi/lib/plugin.js:572:14)
kibserver_1        |        at internals.Plugin.route (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/hapi/lib/plugin.js:542:10)
kibserver_1        |        at createProxy (/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/elasticsearch/lib/create_proxy.js:85:14)
kibserver_1        |        at ScopedPlugin.init [as externalInit] (/usr/share/kibana/src/core_plugins/elasticsearch/index.js:110:37)
kibserver_1        |        at ScopedPlugin.tryCatcher (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
kibserver_1        |        at Promise.attempt.Promise.try (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/method.js:30:24)
kibserver_1        |        at /usr/share/kibana/src/server/plugins/plugin.js:196:46
kibserver_1        |        at next (native)
kibserver_1        |        at step (/usr/share/kibana/src/server/plugins/plugin.js:25:191)
kibserver_1        |        at /usr/share/kibana/src/server/plugins/plugin.js:25:361,
kibserver_1        |   isOperational: true }
```

This one baffles me. I can't seem to find any reference to a "payload timeout" in the ElasticSearch documentation. My web searches suggest this might be coming from hapijs, but I'm not sure how to resolve this. Does anyone out there know?

(Kibana, ElasticSearch, and Logstash are all v 6.1.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're setting the timeout to a value that's too small, it's in ms and the default is 30000 (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.1/settings.html):

> `elasticsearch.requestTimeout`:
>
> **Default: 30000** Time in milliseconds to wait for responses from the back end or Elasticsearch. This value must be a positive integer.

---

What might be possible is that the `elasticsearch.requestTimeout` is used to set the socket timeout in the hapijs and since the default for the payload time out seems to be 10 s ([from here](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/083c7b1536019b678fc7d43fa5ecb90ff8078ac3/API.md#-routeoptionspayloadtimeout)):

> **`route.options.payload.timeout`**
>
> Default value: to 10000 (10 seconds).

It will fail when checking if the payload timeout is shorter than the socket timeout. But that's just an hypotheses and I have failed find any proof in Kibana's code.

Comment: How embarrassing. I had a "not enough 0's" error. *blushes* Well, thank you for pointing that out! I suppose later I might try tweaking `route.options.paylout.timeout` just to see what it does (I'm guessing that would need to be done in the elasticsearch settings, but I don't think it's necessary at this point).

Comment: The part with `route.options.paylout.timeout` was an attempt at explaining where the error was coming from, between the configuration and the error message.